# PHP: safely transform a file name into an URL

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, urlencode, scandir

I wrote a PHP script who scans a directory for pdf files and then create an HTML page with the list of this files and their relative link. The name of the file will be used for the list items.

How can i ensure a good compatibility between special chars and the URL?

For example, i have a file that contains `text 49% text.pdf` and the server is responding to the URL `http://localhost/folder/text%2049%%20text.pdf` with a `Bad Request` error.

I tried using the `urlencode()` with no success. How can i improve my script?

**UPDATE**

`urlencode()` returns me `<a href="text+49%25+text.pdf">text 49% text.pdf</a>`, and with this i get the `Bad Request` error.

Comment: i think if you have a file named by "text 49% text.pdf" physically on your server it's a bad thing. You have to rename file before save it on your server. so if you upload "text é text.pdf" change his name by "text_e_text.pdf" for example ! It will prevent those url errors ;)

Comment: As i'm using the file name to fill the list, i avoided the underscores that i usually use for every file i put on the server. I know i can escape them but isn't there a way to achieve what originally requested? **PS** the error comes even with your solution

Comment: Can't you avoid the % symbol inside the file name??@vismark

Comment: @SubinThomas that's part of the document title and it must appear in that way...i need to improve the script, not to avoid hard/particular situations

Comment: I tried urlencode() and getting "test+49%25+test.pdf". @vismark

Comment: @SubinThomas that's correct, i'm getting that too but the server is returning the error. I've also updated the question with this info.

Comment: @vismark Check my answer and try it. I think it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `rawurlencode()`. That will convert both % to %25 and spaces to %20

Answer (score 0):

`text%2049%%20text.pdf` giving you a `Bad Request` is correct. 
Because `49%` should be encoded as `49%25`.

The result link should be like this: 
    `<a href="text%2049%25%20text.pdf"> text 49% text.pdf</a>`

I use `urlencode()` for this without problem.

Sorry for not posting as a comment, do not have enough point.

Comment: I know percentage in URL are escaped with `%25` and i can do it manually, but isn't there a function like `urlencode()` to escape all these strange situations as i might not being foreseeing all of them? I can't check if it works each time a new file is being uploaded with a special character in the name...

Comment: Don't worry ming, but as i said in the question, `urlencode()` is not working in this case...